# Plotting relationship between two variables when their relationship is given by a polynomial

Tags: plotting

I have the following equation and I want to plot a graph with $\mathfrak{p}$ in the $x$-axis and $i$ in the $y$-axis. I don't have a specific range for $i$ but I would like to see what happens when $\mathfrak{p}$ is in between 0 and 3.

The equation is:
$$0.74\mathfrak{p} i^9-0.0045(\mathfrak{p}-13)i^8+7i^7-426\left(\frac{1}{\mathfrak{p}}-0.0065\right)i^6+901i^5-11i^4-(\mathfrak{p}^2+5\mathfrak{p})i+1=0$$

Can someone please help me with this?

I am new to Mathematica and I am completely lost with this one.

I would also appreciate it if you can tell me how to plot another curve (basically the same equation with different coefficients) on the same graph.

Thank you!

Comment: `ContourPlot` is work.BTW, you should post the Mathematica code instead of TeX.

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks so much for telling me this. I am new to mathematica.SE and didn't know this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 0.74 p*i^9 - 0.0045 (p - 13) i^8 + 7 i^7 - 426 (1/p - 0.0065) i^6 + 
      901 i^5 - 11 i^4 - (p^2 + 5 p) i + 1 == 0 //
    Rationalize // Simplify;

ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn, {p, 0, 3}, {i, -1, 20},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {p, i}),
 Epilog -> Inset[ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn, {p, 0, 1}, {i, -1/2, 1},
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    WorkingPrecision -> 20,
    MaxRecursion -> 5,
    FrameLabel ->
     (Style[#, 10, Bold] & /@ {p, i})],
   {2, 13}]]
```

[image]

The inset with the blowup was added since there was a lot of dead space in the plot.

For multiple equations use `ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eqn1, eqn2,...}, ...]`

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to Mathematica and trying to figure things as I go. This is very helpful!

Comment: I tried using your code to plot a different function of the same sort and Mathematica gives me an error saying that the precision of the argument function is less than WorkingPrecision. I have posted this new function as a seperate question on Mathematica.SE Could you please take a look at this and help me with a code if you have time? Also I'd like to know how to fix that error. Thank you so much! https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250541/plotting-relationship-between-two-variables-when-their-relationship-is-given-by